# Android Emulator not using the RAM I provided from Xamarin AndroidDeviceManager

Tags: android, xamarin, android-virtual-device, android-device-manager

I'm doing Xamarin.Android development form Visual Studio 2017. And I find my AVD runs out of memory (88% usage) after a few hours debugging and become sluggish, no matter how I use it, be it start-stopping my App frequently from VS2017 or just leave it lying doing nothing.

I want to give it more memory so I configured 8GB memory from Android Device Manager. I'm running Windows 10 64bit on my PC which has 32GB RAM so there's plenty left.

[image]

However after I boot up the AVD again it shows only 3GB memory instead of the 8GB I gave it. Did I miss something?

I'm using Android Emulator 30.0.12-6466327. Android Device Manager is provided by Xamarin SDK form VS2017.

[image]

Comment: Restart your PC after update the info of Emulator . In addition , VS 2019 had released . You update the IDE to the latest version .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Restarted PC to no avail. I'll try VS2019 later and see it makes a difference. Is there any reason behind this strange behavior?